# Power Query - How to use an Excel 2016 cell value in a Oracle SQL query

Tags: oracle, powerquery

I decided to use Power Query in Excel 2016 to load and interpret some data that I'm retrieving from an Oracle DB. I have several sheets that I want to load based on a specific execution code, EXE_ID, that may be different according  to the data I intend to see.

What I want to do should be relatively straight forward, at least according to all the tutorials that I've seen so far: I just want to specify the EXE_ID in one single sheet and want that all the queries in every sheet are able to read it and load the information accordingly. The problem is that I'm always getting some kind of error.

Here's my latest attempt:

I created a simple table with a header named Current_EXE_ID and a single value bellow, 43.

Afterwards I created a Blank Query where I added the following code:

```
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="GetExeId"]}[Content],
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Current_EXE_ID", type text}}),
  #"Current_EXE_ID" = #"Changed Type"{0}[Current_EXE_ID]
in
  #"Current_EXE_ID"
```

The ideia was simply to read the value in the table, 43, convert it to text and store it in the #"Current_EXE_ID" variable, so that I could retrieve it from a differente sheet.

When I try to include variable in a query in a different sheet and try access it I'm getting the following error message:

> [Expression.Error] The import CUrrent_EXE_ID matches no exports. Did
>   you miss a module reference?

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
let
    Source = Oracle.Database("<DB_NAME>", [Query="SELECT * #(lf)FROM TABLE_NAME#(lf)WHERE EXE_ID = " & #"Current_EXE_ID"])
in
    Source
```

I've also tried different approaches, such as creating a parameter table with the following code attached via Blank Query page as well:

```
(ParameterName as text) =>
let
ParamSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameters"]}[Content],
ParamRow = Table.SelectRows(ParamSource, each ([Parameter] = ParameterName)),
Value=
if Table.IsEmpty(ParamRow)=true
then null
else Record.Field(ParamRow{0},"Value")
in
Value
```

I named the function fnGetExeId and incorporated it the Oracle SQL query

let
    Source = Oracle.Database("", [Query="SELECT * #(lf)FROM TABLE_NAME#(lf)WHERE EXE_ID =" & fnGetExeId("EXE_ID")
])
in
    Source

but I ended up getting this error:

> Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and Number.
>   Details:
>       Operator=&
>       Left=SELECT * #(lf)FROM TABLE_NAME#(lf)WHERE EXE_ID = 
>       Right=43

If someone could at least explain the error causes it would be great!

Thanks in advance!
Miguel

Answer (score 0):

1) The first Expression.Error looks like a typo. Is there any place where the query is referenced as `#"CUrrent_EXE_ID"` instead of `#"Current_EXE_ID"`?

2) It looks like `Record.Field(ParamRow{0},"Value")` is returning a number in the function you posted. If you plan on only using it to build the SQL query, you can change it to `Number.ToText(Record.Field(ParamRow{0},"Value"))`, and then it should work.

If you only need to do a simple WHERE statement, however, you can also use `Table.SelectRows` like so:

`Table.SelectRows(Source, each [EXE_ID] = Current_EXE_ID)`

This is the preferred solution since it allows Power Query to fold further transformations into the query it sends to the server and it removes the risk of SQL injection.